# Find an equation for the conic .

Tags: calculus

**Question-01**: a).Find an equation for the conic that has center at (0, 0); major and minor axes along the coordinate axes; passes through (3, 2) and (1, 6). Sketch the curve, and label the foci, vertices, compute the equation of major and minor axis.

Answer:  The equation is an ellipse: x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1
or b^2x^2 + a^2y^2 = a^2b^2

```
(1,6) is a point on the graph of the ellipse:
```

plug those values in to get   b^2 + 36a^2 = a^2b^2

(3,2) is another point on the graph, plug it in to get

```
                                     9b^2 + 4a^2 = a^2b^2

subtract the equations:   -8b^2 +32a^2 = 0

                                      b^2 = 4a^2
```

then  x^2/a^2 + y^2/4a^2 = 1

```
      9/a^2 + 4/4a^2 = 1

      9/a^2 + 1/a^2 = 1

    9+1 = a^2
```

(**I tried this far this math but now i am not understanding what to do.**)

Comment: You're pretty much done so the equation of the elipse is $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$ which turns into $x^2/10+y^2/40=1$ from there you should be able to finish.

Comment: Brother is my math is ok then?